# systemd service stop always fails

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I am converting our service startup script from SysV to systemd.

Our "service" is a java server running in Netty.

To start the service, in the unit file I have something like:

```
[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=%N
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar ....jar
```

I don't think the exact command is relevant here. It starts just as I expect, and everything runs fine.

To shut down the service we have special URL. So to stop the service, in the unit file I have:

```
ExecStop=/usr/bin/wget -t3 -T5 -q -O- http://localhost:7090/shutdown
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
```

Whenever I call `systemctl stop server` I always end up with:

```
● server.service - some Control System server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-03-24 00:54:19 UTC; 3s ago
  Process: 8756 ExecStop=/usr/bin/wget -t3 -T5 -q -O- http://localhost:7090/shutdown (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8597 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar ....jar (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

The service stops. But why do I get `failed (Result: exit-code)`?

**Edit**: Running `journalctl -u server`, I see:

```
Mar 24 19:10:10 hive systemd[1]: Stopping some Control System server...
Mar 24 19:10:10 hive server[13731]: SHUTDOWN STARTING. END IN 15 SEC
Mar 24 19:10:10 hive systemd[1]: server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=143/n/a
Mar 24 19:10:10 hive systemd[1]: server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 24 19:10:10 hive systemd[1]: Stopped some Control System server.
```

Comment: Did you find any logging in systemd journal? Command `journalctl -u abc.service`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is essentially answered on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/695849).

In summary:

> Exit code 143 means that the program received a SIGTERM signal to
> instruct it to exit, but it did not handle the signal properly.
>
> [This can be suppressed] by adding the exit code into the unit file as
> a "success" exit status:

```
[Service]
SuccessExitStatus=143
```

Another answer at the link above adds more detail.